# Disassembler for Android to Java

Tags: android, linux, dalvik, disassembly

I'm looking for a decent Android disassembler, preferably free, which disassembles an *.apk, producing Java source code. What I've used so far is `apktool` which is not what I am looking for, because it disassembles an *.apk into *.smali files.

Also I'm on Linux currently. I could use Windows if there is no other choice, though.

Is there such a disassembler?

Comment: [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) => [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) along with [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) (both tools use java), with these steps:

1. Extract the classes.dex file from the apk file
2. Use dex2jar to create a jar file
3. Use jd-gui to explore the classes and/or export to java source

Notice obfuscated code will be hard to read, but that is to be expected.

Comment: you can use dex2jar directly on an `apk`

Comment: Cool, didn't know that :) Going to try that out next time.